# Validate custom fields before save using WordPress Rest API

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, advanced-custom-fields, validation

I want to add custom validation to post(custom post type) before it save into the WordPress. I am using the Rest API to insert the post to custom post type. What I need is the fields which I created using ACF(Advance Custom Fields) should be validated before it actually save into the WordPress Backend. I tried to find the hook action for before save but no luck so far. 
Quick help will be appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But When I call the API using the POST method for storing the data into custom post type. It's not validates the fields which I checked as required in ACF.

Comment: Hi @vikrantzilpe The above functions not worked for me for custom post type. Do you have any work around here?

Comment: Thanks for look into this but above link is only guide me how to create custom post type.

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Do you find any hooks actions that runs before saving the posts where I can validate each fields that passed into rest api?

Comment: add_action('acf/validate_save_post', 'my_acf_validate_save_post', 10, 0);

Comment: @vikrantzilpe I already tried my luck with this but not worked. Do you have any idea about WordPress hooks before save? The above is ACF save hook.

Comment: add_action('save_post','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id){
    global $post; 
    if ($post->post_type != 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME'){
        return;
    }
    //if you get here then it's your post type so do your thing....
}

Comment: @vikrantzilpe This is the after save hook. I need exact before save post hook :(

Comment: exact before save post hook not available in wp

Comment: apply_filters( "rest_pre_insert_{$this->post_type}", $prepared_post, $request );
@vikrantzilpe worked for me.

Comment: ok means your problem solve goood

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Yup, I posted as well as answers, So in future any one encountered with such scenario then this thread would be helpful. Thanks again for your efforts. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching a lot to API documentation, I found the solution to my problem finally:

```
function my_rest_prepare_post(  $prepared_post, $request ) {

...

}
add_filter( 'rest_pre_insert_posttype', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Just an observation, it should be 2 instead of 3. The filter only takes 2 arguments, this is the core code: `return apply_filters( "rest_pre_insert_{$this->post_type}", $prepared_post, $request );`. And a hint for those looking onto this filter, we should return a `WP_Error` to abort the item insertion.